# How to further test my Gdx-pay implementation?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play, gdx-pay

I am working on implementing gdx-pay into my android game. I basically copied the gdx-pay example program off the github tutorial page since I don't understand how to implement it myself. Everything seems to be working but I am still not sure how I would further check if the transactions would actually work. I figure I will not be able to test it any further since the app is not acutally released.

Basically I want to know if there is anything else that I need to do. Right now the gui works fine and I am able to click the purchase button. However, nothing happens when I press the buttons besides a message in my logcat saying: "D/c: In App Purchasing SDK - Sandbox Mode: sendPurchaseRequest"

Does this mean that it is working? Should there be something else that pops up for my password, verification, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a real device or the emulator? As far as I know, you need a physical device for the payment to work.
If you publish your app (even as Alpha or Beta release), you should be able to perform a dummy Purchase using your account (Google offers this feature - if it detects the Android phone username is the same as the Google Developers account, it won't actually charge you, but perform a fictitious transaction).

Comment: I am using an real device. SO what you are saying is that even though the app isnt released, I should still be getting a prompt to complete the transaction? Because I am not.

Answer (score 0):

Testing depends on your payment service.

There are testing instructions in the corresponding readme files: [Google Billing](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/tree/master/gdx-pay-android-googlebilling) [Amazon](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/tree/master/gdx-pay-android-amazon)

Sandbox mode sounds like you are using Amazon?

Comment: I think you also commented on my reddit post lol. But yeah I forgot to change it from amazon to google billing.